# Enforce same value for the combination of two other values

Tags: database, oracle, constraints

I have a table `T`, where I have 4 (integer) columns, `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. There is already a `UNIQUE` constraint on `ABC`, but I would need to write a constraint enforcing, that for the same `AB` combination, the `D` has the same value, no matter what `C` is. I.e.

```
A B C D Note
1 1 1 1 AB is 1,1, D is 1
1 1 2 1
1 1 3 2 wrong! D must be 1, because AB is 1,1
1 1 4 1 ok
2 1 1 5 ok, it's a new AB combination, so a new D value is possible
2 1 2 5 D must be 5 here (and for any following row with AB 2,1)
etc.
```

I have no idea where to start, and my Google-fu is weak in this case.

Comment: Is your data model properly normalized?  It sounds like you want a parent table with a key of (A,B) that has D as a column and then a child table that has a key of (A, B, C) and a foreign key back to the parent.  Is there a reason that you're doing this all in a single table?

Comment: @JustinCave yeah, that's the option (to change the model), but I'd like to avoid it, as it would induce a way too many changes to the current ORM model. The ABC columns already exist (they are actually foreign keys to other tables), D is a new one holding an actual value.

Comment: Looking at the first 3 rows in your example. You said that 1st is OK as well as the 2nd, while 3rd is wrong because D = 2 and it should be 1. But, why isn't it vice versa? This is a relational database, rows aren't stored in any particular order. Why wouldn't [A = 1, B = 1, D = 2] be correct and [A = 1, B = 1, D = 1] wrong (because we'd expect D = 2)? It depends on your starting point, and there's none. This is dummy data, I guess in reality it looks quite different.

Comment: @Littlefoot the thing is, you are inserting the rows in a particular order. So after inserting a `1,1,1,1` row, you can insert a `1,1,2,1` row, but I want to prevent you from inserting a `1,1,2,2` row. Actually, in my app, it won't be possible to do this via UI or WS, so here I am safe, but I would like to prevent this even on DB level (as the customer's DB admin has an access to the DB). It's just an additional safety measure, not something I couldn't go without.

Comment: Are you allowed to create certain objects in your database, I would be particularly interested if you can create a materialized view log on the base table or creating materialized view using the base table ?